# How to include bash profile in etc

Tags: linux, macos

I have a .bash_profile created that contains the environmental variables set. This was created for a particular user, say user1. I now want to reuse this environment variables also for other users, but I do not want to create yet another .bash_profile. I have a postgres user to which I would like to share this .bash_profile.

I understand that I could do this with /etc/profile. How could I reference the .bash_profile in the /etc/profile?

Comment: So you want `/etc/profile` to source the `/home/some_user/.bash_profile`? I don't know if this is very clean. What about moving this content to `/etc/profile` instead?

Comment: Yes, how could I have /etc/profile source the /home/some_user/.bash_profile?

Comment: Typing `source /home/some_user/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Cool! That worked! That is what I wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the common content to `/etc/profile`. This way, it will be available for all users when they log in.

<sub>In comments I mentioned that you can modify the `/etc/profile` file and add the following line: `source /home/<some_user>/.bash_profile`. This will make this file to be sourced by all users when they log in. DO NOT DO IT: it allows a single user subverting the entire system (see comments below by [trojanfoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299924/trojanfoe)).</sub>

Comment: Awful solution.  Moving the content to `/etc/profile` is the only way to avoid a single user subverting the entire system.

Comment: I think I might add `rm -rf /` to my profile.  Anyone see any issues?

Comment: @trojanfoe again: I agree :D Updated the answer to make it more clear that this is *not* the way to go. Feel free to edit if you think it should be expressed differently.

Comment: You can edit it.  Remove all reference to using a file within a user's home directory.  The only way is to add the content to `/etc/profile` which is under admin control.